# ScaleTransform in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

So, I have this working in my Silverlight XAML. How would I convert it to be done in the VB.Net codebehind?

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="MyScale" ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75"/>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

The Grid I am transforming is my LayoutRoot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it:

```
    Dim ScaleDown As New ScaleTransform
    ScaleDown.ScaleX = "0.75"
    ScaleDown.ScaleY = "0.75"
    LayoutRoot.RenderTransform = ScaleDown
```

Comment: This is just awful.  You really need to use Option Strict On for a while to learn to stop writing code like this.

Comment: I'll try that for my next application. Although it's likely that'll be HTML5/Javascript rather than Silverlight/VB.Net.